# Return event from flyout to calling page in MAUI?

Tags: maui

I'm very new to MAUI and cross platform development. I have a page "ItemsPage" that has a Flyout that builds a filter for a query.  The button "Search" on the Flyout closes the Flyout after storing the query variables in a class object where the calling page, "ItemsPage" would use that variable and execute the query.  I can't figure out how to consume this.  Is there an event that is called after the Flyout is closed on the "ItemsPage"?

Tried navigation methods; but not getting anything from them.

Comment: have you tried `Disappearing`?  Or the page could raise a custom event when Search is clicked

Comment: So would the Disappearing be on the AppShell page or the "ItemsPage"? If I had a custom event on the Search button click, AppShell page, would there not have to be an event on the "ItemsPage" to be consumed?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the code to control the flyoutpage, open and close the flyout programmatically.

The flyout can be programmatically opened and closed by setting the `Shell.FlyoutIsPresented` bindable property to a boolean value that indicates whether the flyout is currently open:

```
<Shell ...
       FlyoutIsPresented="{Binding IsFlyoutOpen}">
</Shell>
```

or you can also use the code below in the code behind.

```
Shell.Current.FlyoutIsPresented = false;
```

Comment: That's really close to what I'm looking for.  How would I implement that in the code behind?  In other words, what method would be watching for the changes?

Comment: You can put the code `Shell.Current.FlyoutIsPresented = false;` in the code behind of the button to control the FlyoutIsPresented.

Comment: So I could not use the hamburger button or swipe to do this?

Comment: I'm having a very difficult time understanding this.  If I have a page "ItemsPage" and I call the Flyout, which is on the AppShell page, and then click a button on the flyout, how does the "ItemsPage" know about it?

Comment: You can check this link about [Open and close the flyout programmatically](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/shell/flyout?view=net-maui-8.0#open-and-close-the-flyout-programmatically).

Comment: I saw this this also; but it doesn't really address the process I'm trying to create. I ended up; however, just using a model page for my filtering and when it closed the OnAppearing Event is available.  Works great.